# JPA One to One mapping with inheritance: 2 Queries for what should be one

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a one to one relationship between a `Media` entitiy and a `MediaAnalysis` entity where the `Media` entity is an abstract base class:

**News Report Entity**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("N")
public class NewsReport extends Media {

    @Column(name = "BODY", nullable = false)
    private String body;

    NewsReport(){}

    public NewsReport(String title, String link, String author, String body) {
        super(title, link, author);
        this.body= body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

**Media Entity**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE
)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", length = 1, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Media {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "LINK", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR", length = 45, nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "media")
    private MediaAnalysis analysis;

    Media(){}

    public Media(String title, String link, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // getters

    public Optional<MediaAnalysis> getAnalysis() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(analysis);
    }
}
```

**Media Analysis**

```
@Entity
public class MediaAnalysis {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SUCCESS", nullable = false)
    private Boolean success;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "MED_ID",
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="MEA_MED_FK")
    )
    private Media media;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    MediaAnalysis() { }

    public MediaAnalysis(Media media, Boolean success, String content) {
        this.media = media;
        this.success = success;
        this.content = content;
    }

    // getters

    public Media getMedia() {
        return media;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Now when I want to use my `AnalysisRepository.getByMedia(..a NewsReport...)`

```
public interface AnalysisRepository extends JpaRepository<MediaAnalysis,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT a FROM MediaAnalysis a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.media WHERE a.media = ?1")
    Optional<MediaAnalysis> getByMedia(Media media);

}
```

To find an `MediaAnalysis` by a `NewsReport` for example I would expect hibernate to run a single `SELECT` query, something like:

> SELECT m.* from mediaanalysis m where m.med_id = ?

But instead when I enable query logging I see 2:

> DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_0_0_, media1_.id as id2_1_1_, mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id3_0_0_, mediaanaly0_.success as success2_0_0_, media1_.author as author3_1_1_, media1_.link as link4_1_1_, media1_.title as title5_1_1_, media1_.body as body6_1_1_, media1_.type as type1_1_1_ from mea_media_analysis mediaanaly0_ left outer join med_media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id where mediaanaly0_.med_id=?
>
> TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
>
> DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_0_1_, mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id3_0_1_, mediaanaly0_.success as success2_0_1_, media1_.id as id2_1_0_, media1_.author as author3_1_0_, media1_.link as link4_1_0_, media1_.title as title5_1_0_, media1_.body as body6_1_0_, media1_.type as type1_1_0_ from mea_media_analysis mediaanaly0_ inner join med_media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id where mediaanaly0_.med_id=?
>
> TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]

It seems to first select the `MediaAnalysis` as expected, but then there's one other query which seem unneccessary. The only difference I can tell between those two queries is the join type. I presume the issue is to do with the `Media` inheritance.

Why is this happening? + What can I do to make sure this is one query?

---

On a further note, if I remove the `@Query` from my repository there is actually **three** queries!.

> DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_0_, mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id3_0_, mediaanaly0_.success as success2_0_ from mea_media_analysis mediaanaly0_ left outer join med_media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id where media1_.id=?
>
> TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
>
> DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select media0_.id as id2_1_0_, media0_.author as author3_1_0_, media0_.link as link4_1_0_, media0_.title as title5_1_0_, media0_.body as body6_1_0_, media0_.type as type1_1_0_, mediaanaly1_.id as id1_0_1_, mediaanaly1_.med_id as med_id3_0_1_, mediaanaly1_.success as success2_0_1_ from med_media media0_ left outer join mea_media_analysis mediaanaly1_ on media0_.id=mediaanaly1_.med_id where media0_.id=?
>
> TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
>
> DEBUG o.h.SQL:92 - select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_0_1_, mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id3_0_1_, mediaanaly0_.success as success2_0_1_, media1_.id as id2_1_0_, media1_.author as author3_1_0_, media1_.link as link4_1_0_, media1_.title as title5_1_0_, media1_.body as body6_1_0_, media1_.type as type1_1_0_ from mea_media_analysis mediaanaly0_ inner join med_media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id where mediaanaly0_.med_id=?
>
> TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]

Comment: What are the queries you see when removing @Query?

Comment: @Kirinya Extra queries added :)

Comment: Can you try using `@OneToOne(optional = false)`?
I think the the `nullable` field of `JoinColumn` only alters the DDL in case you autogenerate the table, not the executed SQL - what `@OneToOne(optional = false)` is doing

Comment: You have two way bindings. Couldn't you just do `aNewsReport.getAnalysis()`?

Comment: Is there other queries in the log when you do this query? Hibernate can trigger many parallel queries when you have an EAGER (`@OneToOne` is EAGER by default), FETCH, `optional=false` and Inheritance combined. Following the sequence of the queries can help you to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with JpaRepository, just (a lot) with Hibernate (& CriteriaBuilder mostly), but some ideas:

- try to map the `@OneToOne` in only one of the two entities (should be MediaAnalysis per your example)
- try to map `MediaAnalysis` as 1:n relation (as if it would be possible to have multiple `MediaAnalysis` per Media, which might well be in my understanding, just perhaps not in your domain).

See if any of that helps with the queries generated.

Answer (score 1):

I try to reproduce your problem in this [dedicated branch in github](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/tree/so-48169664). Except getter setter in entity classes, I change nothing from your code example above especially for Repository class. From what [simple unit test code](https://github.com/xsalefter/test-lazy-hibernate/blob/so-48169664/src/test/java/com/denodev/dao/MediaAnalysisRepositoryTest.java#L48) show me, nothing wrong with your query, and it is generated exactly only 1 query, as follow:

```
---------- WATCH GENERATED QUERY HERE ----------
2018-01-19 09:20:26.880 DEBUG 22769 --- [main] org.hibernate.SQL : select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_1_0_, media1_.id as id2_0_1_, mediaanaly0_.content as content2_1_0_, mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id4_1_0_, mediaanaly0_.success as success3_1_0_, media1_.author as author3_0_1_, media1_.link as link4_0_1_, media1_.title as title5_0_1_, media1_.body as body6_0_1_, media1_.type as type1_0_1_ from media_analysis mediaanaly0_ left outer join media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id where mediaanaly0_.med_id=?
---------- END OF GENERATED QUERY HERE ----------
```

Nevertheless, your problem arise maybe because:

1. Bug in JPA/Hibernate/Spring Data version you currently use (you don't mentions specifics version here).
2. Unnecessary call in your code in another layer (service, controller layer).

Another thing that maybe helpful is that you could add [`@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Fetch.html) annotation in your relationship, like:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(
    name = "MED_ID",
    nullable = false,
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="MEA_MED_FK")
)
private Media media;
```

But I strongly recommended that you check and or upgrade your libraries version, and/or write DB testing to make sure where's the problem exactly occurs.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve to execute only one database query, is if you specify  the `@OneToOne` relationship only in the owner side, from which I understand is `MediaAnalysis` entity.

```
public class MediaAnalysis {

    // ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MED_ID")
    private Media media;
    // ...
}
```

And remove completely `analysis` field from `Media` entity.

Just tried this, and it worked as expected, the only query executed in the Test was:

```
select mediaanaly0_.id as id1_3_0_, 
       media1_.id as id2_2_1_, 
       mediaanaly0_.content as content2_3_0_, 
       mediaanaly0_.med_id as med_id4_3_0_, 
       mediaanaly0_.success as success3_3_0_, 
       media1_.author as author3_2_1_, 
       media1_.link as link4_2_1_, 
       media1_.title as title5_2_1_, 
       media1_.body as body6_2_1_, 
       media1_.type as type1_2_1_ 
from mediaanalysis mediaanaly0_ 
left outer join media media1_ on mediaanaly0_.med_id=media1_.id 
where mediaanaly0_.med_id=?
```

You can find the sample code in [github repository](https://github.com/lzagkaretos/demo-media).